# How to pass array to zabbix external script

Tags: zabbix

is it possible to pass a array to external script? Let me describe a situation and there is maybe a better solution that I am trying.
I have several servers in a cluster and just one is in active state hence should be monitored.
My initial idea was to create external script which is passed an array of possible nodes in cluster and script will find an active one and get appropriate parameters.
The number of nodes in cluster is variable - can happen that there is just one active.

I wanted to avoid a situation having the same template applied to every host and active parameter would just say that this one is worth looking as non active doesn't provide correct info as they are not synchronized.

I tried on macro configuration:

```
{$NODE} -> ( "host1" "host2" )
```

But that does't work
Any hints appreciated
Thx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if what you are trying to do with macros is going to work, I never tried. However, what works for me is:

- creating a "virtual" host and adding there active items that are
  reported using zabbix_send only from active host. passive monitoring
- using the IP address assigned to the active node in cluster or
  monitoring through frontend (http) proxy that forwards all
  connections to the active node.

I hope it helps